# Do monoecious plants have bisexual flowers?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, reproduction, flowers

I used to think that monoecious plants have male (unisexual) flowers and female (unisexual) flowers on the same plant but on different locations. But recently I learnt that monoecious plants also have bisexual flowers,  which means the male part and the female part in the same flower.

Thus, I am confused. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange. Please, read some basics about the terminology (for example [Wikipedia page on plant reproductive morhpology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_reproductive_morphology#Terminology)), then let us know if you still have any misunderstandings by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that [monoecious](https://www.ibiblio.org/pic/botanical_dictionary.htm#M) describes plants where the male and female structures (cones or flowers) are on the same plant but in separate locations. Plants that produce hermaphrodite flowers together with either female or male flowers, are termed [gynomonoecious](https://www.ibiblio.org/pic/botanical_dictionary.htm#G) or [andromonoecious](https://www.ibiblio.org/pic/botanical_dictionary.htm#A), respectively. A plant with separate male, female, and hermaphrodite flowers is [trimonoecious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimonoecy).

Monoecy is not to be confused with [monoicy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoicy). In monoicy, both gametes, sperm and egg, are produced by the gametophyte (e.g., some plants with gametophyte-dominant life cycles [bryophytes]).

Answer (score -1):

Monoecious plants have both female and male flowers in the same plant. They can be male flowers, female flowers or a mixture of the two in the same plant.

Comment: You repeated what the questioner wrote and even left out some detail they established. You should provide better detail, maybe break down what word monoecious means or provide explanation of the other types of reproduction in plant to make the point of a monecious plant more clear.